# How to pass values to web application from a windows service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web application that require client machine's Motherboard number and other details.
I have created a windows service to get machine details (like motherboard number).
I want to pass these information to my asp.net web application.
How it is possible?

please answer me..

Comment: You can Use WebServices for this. (.asmx file)

Comment: Sorry..I am new to windows and web service..Could you pls give some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass them per se. What you could do is write this information in a database/file/etc from your windows service and then read it from the web application.